# Difference between CSS3 transitions' ease-in and ease-out

Tags: css, css-transitions

What’s the difference between CSS3 transitions’ `ease-in`, `ease-out`, etc.?

Comment: I realise I'm replying to a very old comment, but I need to point out for the benifit of anyone else reading this that w3schools is not the source of the standard (read http://www.w3fools.com/). The correct link is http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property

Answer (score 308, accepted):

CSS3's transitions and animations support easing, formally called a "timing function". The common ones are `ease-in`, `ease-out`, `ease-in-out`, `ease`, and `linear`, or you can specify your own using `cubic-bezier()`.

- `ease-in` will start the animation slowly, and finish at full speed.
- `ease-out` will start the animation at full speed, then finish slowly.
- `ease-in-out` will start slowly, be fastest at the middle of the animation, then finish slowly.
- `ease` is like `ease-in-out`, except it starts slightly faster than it ends.
- `linear` uses no easing.
- Finally, [here's a great description](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/) of the `cubic-bezier` syntax, but it's usually not necessary unless you want some very precise effects.

Basically, easing out is to slow to a halt, easing in is to slowly accelerate, and linear is to do neither. You can find more detailed resources at the [documentation for `timing-function` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/timing-function).

And if you do want the aforementioned precise effects, the amazing Lea Verou’s [cubic-bezier.com](http://cubic-bezier.com) is there for you! It’s also useful for comparing the different timing functions graphically.

Another, [the `steps()` timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps%28%29_class_of_timing-functions), acts like `linear`, but only performs a finite number of steps between the transition’s beginning and its end. `steps()` has been most useful to me in CSS3 animations, rather than in transitions; a good example is in loading indicators with dots. Traditionally, one uses a series of static images (say eight dots, two changing colour each frame) to produce the illusion of motion. With a `steps(8)` animation and a `rotate` transform, you’re using motion to produce the illusion of separate frames! How fun.

Comment: Nice description. Solved my query.