# Rotate element to 360deg using CSS3 Animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a loader animation using CSS3. Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/raaj-obuli/pen/RPeLer

If you look at the code, I've entered the css, in `@keyframe` defn, for rotating the squares from `0deg` to `360deg` ( as like below ). But the dices are not rotating. Please  help on this and also let me know if you need more details.

```
@keyframes tilt{
  0%{
    transform: scale($scaleMin) rotate($rotateStart);
  }
  50%{
   transform: scale($scaleMax);
   background: #BC11FF;
   box-shadow: 0 0 2px #D467FF;
  }
  95%,100%{
   transform: scale($scaleMin) rotate($rotateEnd);
   background: #11A8FF;
   box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

PS. CSS is written using SCSS in the code sample.

Comment: Probably the addition of `rotate($rotateMid)` inside the `50%` keyframe block will help you?

Comment: Nope. Adding 'rotate()' at 50% causes a pause of the animation in the middle for fraction of seconds.

Comment: that _pause_ is thanks to the `ease-out`. if you can set it to `linear` and set your `$rotateMid` to `180deg` and apply this `$rotateMid` to the `50%` block, this may produce the result you are looking for.

Comment: yeah, as @TahirAhmed said, use linear animation: tilt #{$animDuration}s linear infinite;

Comment: That works!! Thanks a lot @TahirAhmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing the `rotate()` in `50%` section.

```
$rotateMid: 225deg;/*added, adjust the value as needed*/

span {
  animation: tilt #{$animDuration}s linear infinite; /*changed to linear*/
}

50%{
  transform: scale($scaleMax) rotate($rotateMid); /*changed/added*/
}
```

Updated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbJmbO?editors=110

Differences between the transition timing functions:

> - `ease-in` will start the animation slowly, and finish at full speed.
> - `ease-out` will start the animation at full speed, then finish slowly.
> - `ease-in-out` will start slowly, be fastest at the middle of the animation, then finish slowly.
> - `ease` is like `ease-in-out`, except it starts slightly faster than it ends.
> - `linear` uses no easing.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636239/483779

Comment: Here is what I wanted achieve, http://codepen.io/raaj-obuli/pen/RPeLer?editors=110. But observe there is a pause at 50%-th keyframe which I don't want. I just need a smooth rotation.

Comment: If you don't mind, I just wanna ask you another query here related @keyframe. As per MDN doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), any left out property in between the keyframes would be interpolated (unless not defined in first & last keyframes). I am just wondering, why the rotate() property value in 50% is not interpolated here ?

Comment: I think the problem is your previous keyframe setting is *invalid*, it's not about *interpolated*.