# CSS3 transition ease vs. ease-in-out

Tags: css, css-transitions

According to this article on W3C for [CSS Transitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property), it is said to be

**ease**

> The ease function is equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1).

**ease-in-out**

> The ease-in-out function is equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1)

And I think the difference is obvious in terms of numbers, but what is the actual difference and why should one have an option of `ease-in-out` separately?

Could somebody please explain the actual usage?

**UPDATE**

This may be regarded as a duplicate for

[Difference between CSS3 transitions' ease-in and ease-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629346/difference-between-css3-transitions-ease-in-and-ease-out)

But it is not, as the accepted answer on the referenced question just tells:

> `ease` is like `ease-in-out`, except it starts slightly faster than it ends.

And I already know that. My question is, as stated above, about the practical usage.

Comment: Its for the animation transition. for example a designer wants an animation of his design that goes in slowly and goes out slightly faster all with in the same 2 second duration, he'll use the ease-in-out transition to do that.

Comment: What exactly are you asking that you can't directly observe for yourself?

Comment: It is very nicely explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629346/difference-between-css3-transitions-ease-in-and-ease-out)

Comment: @TylerH I've asked it as clear as I can: Practically, why does `ease-in-out` exist? @hkasera No it does not, BTW thanks for sharing the link

Comment: That's about as good an answer as you're going to get; it answers exactly what you asked here. Its usage is the same as any of the other timing bezier curves; people like that timing.

Comment: Re: your edit: it's a timing function; there is no practical usage. If you want your transitions to happen at a variable rate, you use a bezier timing curve. Just like how some CSS colors are defined by name.

Comment: [This UX Collective article](https://uxdesign.cc/the-ultimate-guide-to-proper-use-of-animation-in-ux-10bd98614fa9#52da) explains the usage of different easing methods quite nicely. "Whenever you doubt what type of motion to use in your animation, use standard curve [(ease/ease-in-out)]." It goes on to explain "asymmetric curves", which for an ease-in-out animation is equal to the `ease` CSS value, where `ease-in-out` is symmetric.