# Using ease with css animation

Tags: html, css

```css
.about5 {
    animation: 
    fade 4s ease forwards; animation-delay: 5s;} 



     @keyframes fade {
     0% { opacity: 0; }
     50% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}}
```

```html
<div class="about5">About</div>
```

The animation delays for 5s correctly, but before fading, flashes once. Why? Is this because I'm using `ease` and should I use `linear`?

Page on desktop [here](https://4309.co.uk/about-us).

Comment: you need to set opacity:0 inside the element

Comment: How?..............

Comment: `.about5` does not have it's opacity set to `0` initially, so it's essentially `1` at the start - then, as soon as the animation starts, it's set to `0` and then fades in. Adding `.about5 { opacity: 0; ... }` will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want your content to fade-out, you could set the opacity to the 0% keyframe at 1 like this:

```css
...
@keyframes fade {
 0% { opacity: 1; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
100% { opacity: 0;}}
```

For more information about ease & linear, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636239/12287623) could explain it way better than I could :)